# MY SQL Workbench: Errors after executing SQL script file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm totally new to coding and started learning MY SQL after learning a bit of HTML and CSS. I have installed MSQL and MySQL workbench and started using it after familiarising myself with the panel. The issue I have is after opening the SQL file from the folder course I'm doing and executing the entire code, I receive these error messages and can't figure out how to fix it.

Errors:

```
01:00:18    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `sql_invoicing` 
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1008 Can't drop database 'sql_invoicing'; database doesn't exist   0.000 sec

01:00:18    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `sql_invoicing` 
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1008 Can't drop database 'sql_invoicing'; database doesn't exist   0.000 sec

01:00:18    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `sql_invoicing` 
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1008 Can't drop database 'sql_invoicing'; database doesn't exist   0.000 sec
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those are not errors. Those are warnings. Warnings are different from errors in mysql since they do not stop the execution of your script.

They are telling you that there is no `sql_invoicing` database so the command doesn't need to be run to drop that database. Which is good.

You can totally ignore these warnings. They are just there to provide more information to you, and help you decide if you truly need those commands. For example, you can take out those DROP DATABASE commands entirely and it wouldn't affect your script one bit.

However, it is good practice for scripts to drop a database before it creates one of the same name, that way your script doesn't have a real error occur when trying and failing to create the database. If that happened it would halt the entire script and you would have to fix the error and start over.
The error would look like this:
`ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'sql_invoicing'; database exists`

As it is right now, you can check your database and see that it was created and all your other commands ran successfully. The drop database commands didn't run because they didn't need to run at all. But they will run if you decide to run the script again because now the `sql_invoicing` database does exist since it was created when you ran the script.

Also of note: If you didn't have the 'IF EXISTS' clause in those drop database statements then it would throw an error. Alternatively for CREATE DATABASE statements you can add the 'IF NOT EXISTS' clause which would ensure that doesn't throw an error either in case the database does already exist.

Comment: Thanks a million. Sorry for using the wrong term, I'm totally new to MySQL.

Comment: No worries, MySQL is a great RDBMS to learn. Keep it up. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

Thta is normal behaviour. instead of throwing an error and stopping all activities.

you get a warning and all following commands go ahead.

> IF EXISTS is used to prevent an error from occurring if the database does not exist.

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.